# How upload file and JSON data in one HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, nestjs

There is a small application written in NestJs. In it I created a service BFF (backend for frontend). In this service I send POST request to create a user and at the same time I want to send user's avatar in this request.
To do this I send this request from the VSCode editor:

```
POST http://localhost:3344/api/users/register HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="application/json"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Mark",
  "email": "trainer6@gmail.com",
  "password": "abcdefg",
  "gender": "Male",
  "role": "Trainer",
  "birthDate": "2002-02-02",
  "level": "Professional",
  "trainingType": "Box",
  "certificate": "certificate2.pdf",
  "personalTraining": "true"
}

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="test.png"
Content-Type: image/png

< /Desktop/test.png

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

But this request does not work.
On the server side I just get an empty object.
How to properly describe the request?

I tried specifying Content-Type: multipart/related, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Hello @TupoScrip, I think that the framework's documentation would be a nice place to start, to understand how files are handled in NestJS: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely this line:

```
Content-Type: multipart/data
```

It should be

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

Comment: Fixed it. Unfortunately, it did not help.
When I send a request, I get an error: `{"statusCode": 400,
  "message": "File is required",
  "error": "Bad Request"}`